# IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0? How to fix?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I'm working with the forest cover type dataset. I've read in the data, created dummies for the categorical features, and now I'm looking to transform the dummies to condense the table before feeding it into the neural net. I'd like to condense it from 55 columns down to 13.

Here's my code:

```
soil_type_values = [f"soil_type_{idx+1}" for idx in range(40)]

soil_type = df2.iloc[:, 14:53].apply(
    lambda x: soil_type_values[0::1][x.to_numpy().nonzero()[0][0]], axis=1)
```

When I run this code I get an error that says `"IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0."` Any suggestions on how I can fix this? I've attached a screenshot of the dataset and the traceback for reference.

[Dataset Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2eh5I.png)

[Error and Traceback](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vq4b0.png)

Answer (score 0):

I can get the same error with:

```
In [165]: np.zeros(5).nonzero()[0][0]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  Input In [165] in <cell line: 1>
    np.zeros(5).nonzero()[0][0]
IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0
```

So a starting guess is that `x` is all zeros.  But only you can test that.